# Why I can't create an Ingress resource on Google Container Service?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm following the [http load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) tutorial for creating an Ingress resource for load balancing.

As seen in the tutorial, the Ingress config file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta2
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: nginx
    servicePort: 80
```

But once I try to create the resource, I always get back this error:

> Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "basic-ingress.yaml": Ingress in version "v1beta2" cannot be handled as a Ingress: no kind "Ingress" is registered for version "extensions/v1beta2"

In the past, I saw similar errors when a value wasn't in the right type (number instead of string), but now that doesn't seem the case.

I tried in both 1.7.8-gke.0     (default) and 1.8.1-gke.1 (latest) versions.

Any help would be really much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Hm, seems that changing the apiVersion to `extensions/v1beta1` does the trick.

[edit] Google Cloud support said that's probably a typo in the documentation. Case solved!